# Unanswered Questions on StackOverflow - tag search not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, unanswered-questions

On the "Unanswered Questions" page of stackoverflow.com, clicking on one of the tags in the "Unanswered Tags" list doesn't have any affect on the list of questions shown. For example, the top question on that page at the moment is tagged with *vista*, *graphics*, *winforms* and *.net*, but clicking the *c#* tag in the Unanswered Tags list doesn't remove this question.

Also I've noticed that on this site multiple selections of unanswered tags are anded together, but this doesn't happen on stackoverflow.com either.

This all works fine on stackoverflow's Questions page!

Comment: Confirmed      .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've changed this so tag selections override "My Tags"